# When I refresh the Web Page, it doesn't load the content from cache . The content is actually available in the cache and expires every 4 hrs

Tags: asp.net, caching, get, refresh, outputcache

I have these cache headers set

```
    Context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(refresh));
    Context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(refresh);
    Context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
    Context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
    Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Do i have to set anything else for the caching to work when page is refreshed as well?

Answer (score 0):

For programmatically places a page content in client(browser), proxy and servers cache you need do this:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15));
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
```